# Inheriting a subtype

Tags: c#, inheritance

Ok, this may be an easy question but its been so long since I've done it.

I have a library (libA) that contains classes.   I want to create a new library (libB) that inherits and extends a class from libA:

```
public class c1:libA.c1(){}
```

One of the methods in libA.c1 returns another class defined in libA:

```
public c2 m1(){}
```

When all done, I want to utilize libB without any references defined to libA in the future code.  However, I cannot seem to be able to do it because I have to have a definition of c2 somewhere and simply inheriting:

```
public c2:libAc2(){}
```

doesn't seem to do it.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to expose c2 through libB and "hide" libA  to any programs that reference libB?

Comment: When you talk about hiding things through "libB", are you saying that you also do not want to include "libA"?  E.G. The consumer would only reference "libB"?

Comment: You're going to need a reference to libA at some point regardless. Unless you do some fancy runtime loading of the class. At which point, you can access and instantiate instances of libA's classes, but you won't be able to do a great deal with them in terms of subclassing in libB, etc.

Comment: What is the problem you try to fix? Why is seeing public classes from `libA` an issue? You cannot hide `libA` at all. If you extend classes from `libA` so that they become unusable in the context of using `libB` the this may solve your problem.

Comment: The best you can do would be to simply refactor the classes from libA into libB, if you have the source, and then mark those classes `internal` to libB.

Comment: Wouldn't the reference to libA be compiled into the libB library?  libB will have the reference.  I guess I should have said that these are all class libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a chain of reference like this...

`Application - libB - libA`

Then you will need to include a reference to libA, otherwise it will simply not build your application. libA is a dependency of libB, after all. You're going to need it to run your application.

You can do some fancy loading of classes at runtime, loading assemblies manually, but this won't allow you to write code based on them, as such. So, it won't be of much use to you here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

My best advice would be to refactor the code from libA into libB, provided you have the source code for libA. Then mark the classes you wish to hide from outside the assembly as internal.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx

Comment: Thanks ManoDestra, I forgot to mention that both libA and libB are class libraries.   I think that would preclude needing to have a reference to libA in anything that uses libB (or am I wrong).

Comment: I assumed that libA and libB were class libraries :) Yes, anything that uses libA will require a reference to libA. And if you have an application that only uses libB, it will still need a reference to libA, as it is a dependency of libB.

Comment: That doesn't seem to jibe ManoDestra.   I have already created an inherited class (libB) and am using it in a project that has absolutely no visible reference to libA yet I am able to use the functionality of the libA class by using the methods of libB.   I just checked to make sure I don't have libA in my reference list and I don't.  I do have libB however, as I figured.  I am not necessarily saying that I don't have to have the libA.dll available to the project, its just not in any reference list for the project.

Comment: Odd. I did a solution with 2 class libraries and a console app. Lib B using a class from Lib A. Console app requiring a class from Lib B. I added a reference from Lib B to Lib A and also a reference from my console app to Lib B. I got a build error stating that the console app is missing a reference to Lib A. `Error 1 The type 'ClassLibraryA.ExampleA' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ClassLibraryA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. C:\Projects\ReferencesTest\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 10 13 ConsoleApplication1`

Comment: :) I swear, I have an app (web app) that references libB and doesn't mention libA anywhere in any reference and it works fine.  Did you build libB independently of your console app?

Comment: They're all in the same solution and declared as project references. If you've built the binaries separately and referenced built assemblies, then you may be able to get away with it.

Comment: They are in the same solution but they are not declared as project references.  or at least they don't appear to be.